# Error when I tried to filter rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, filter

I have dataframe:

```
a1     a2   
4567   k
4565   k
4567   k
6325   p
4569   k
4564   k
4555   k
9567   k
9567   h
```

I want to filter the first column and to add value 1 in the third column if the value starts with 456, and 0 otherwise. SO output should look like this:

```
a1    a2   a3
4567   k   1
4565   k   1
4567   k   1
6325   p   0
4569   k   1
4564   k   1
4555   k   0
9567   k   0
9567   h   0
```

My code for that is:

```
data['a3'] = 0
data.loc[data['a1'].filter(regex =r'456'), 'a3'] = 1
```

But I got the key error. And google isn't helping me as well. :/

Comment: **pandas `filter()` does not filter a dataframe by its contents, it filters it by the index - not what you want!** You want `df[df.where(cond)]`. `filter()` is a terrible historical choice of name, should have been `filter_index()` or something, but it's too late to change now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC using `np.where` and `//`（divisor）

```
df['New'] = np.where(df.a1//10==456,1,0)

#           np.where((df.a1//10).isin([456,xxx,yyy]),1,0)

df
     a1 a2  New
0  4567  k    1
1  4565  k    1
2  4567  k    1
3  6325  p    0
4  4569  k    1
5  4564  k    1
6  4555  k    0
7  9567  k    0
8  9567  h    0
```

Fix your code `startswith`

```
data['a3'] = 0
data.loc[data['a1'].astype(str).str.startswith('456'), 'a3'] = 1
```

Why [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) isn't work , since filter is filter the dataframe and not return the position for assignment , so that may cause it failed and it is for `index` and `columns`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is the test frame, my a1 column has many more numbers and its not equal.

Comment: @Neven that  is number , you can not apply string function with it , let me update

Comment: I forgot to mention, I converted it before in string  with this line:     data['a1'] = data['a1'].astype(str)

Comment: I will test it now. :)

Comment: @Neven if you have more value need to check , do with `np.where((df.a1//10).isin([456,xxx,yyy]),1,0)`

Comment: Thank you!! You can put that in your answer to make the answer useable for a bigger audience. And btw startwith worked for me. :)

Comment: It helps to explain that pandas `filter()` does not filter a dataframe by its contents, it filters it by the index - generally not the user wants. So usually the user wants `df[df['colname'].where(cond)]`